# Is installing laminate over parquet on concrete likely to trap moisture?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring, laminate-floor

So I am reading [this article](https://readytodiy.com/can-you-should-you-put-laminate-over-parquet-0051/) which sounds like a relief to me. It says that you can safely install laminate flooring over parquet as long as it is flat and without defects.

In my case it is a basement that, like many basements needs a dehumidifier during the summer. I do not run it a lot but I do need to do it from time to time. I guess that is humidity that comes out of the floors (finished basement, walls are insulated, and have vapor barrier). The parquet is like thi:

[image]

I am considering installing quality vinyl flooring (planks) with underlayment attached.

Will this trap moisture underneath that could lead to mold problems?

Comment: The glue and the finish sealer on the parquet probably already is a half decent moisture barrier.  Any mold would be under the parquet, so if you can pop up a couple of pieces should tell.  If the parquet is in good condition, it should be able able to be refinished, it usually is just small hardwood pieces, unlike vinyl flooring, which needs replacement.

Comment: what do you mean by refinished ? Like polish to remove the sealer and reaply sealer or stain? It looks old fashion/design. I want something more modern

Comment: Refinish is usually sanding and applying something like  polyurethane, but if you want a different look, then should have no problem with the vinyl planks.  Parquet usually does not like moisture/water, so if it is good and tight to the floor then should not have moisture problems.

Comment: Seems a shame to lose a real wood parquet floor in good condition under a layer of laminate, but de gustibus; you're the one living with it. You might want to consider installing the new layer as a floating floor, so the parquet is preserved undamaged should someone+a future buyer?) want to return to it.

Answer (score 1):

Wood floors need to be able to breath so putting any impervious floor covering on top of a parquet flooring can cause it to sweat and move.  Its a commercial risk we wouldn't take